# Dúvidas sobre objetos em vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou trabalhando agora com vba, porém é uma linguagem que tive pouco contato na graduação, gostaria de tirar uma dúvidas.

Quando uma macro em um arquivo excel chama outro arquivo excel que também possui macro que estava fechado não ocorre erro algum, porém você tenta rodar uma macro com outra aberta ocorre um erro, exemplo:

Arquivo excel "A" roda e chama "B", termina a execução como previsto até o fim do processo, porém ao rodar o mesmo "A" deixando o "B" ou qualquer outra macro aberta (mesmo que não rodando) ocorre um erro.

Outra dúvida que eu tenho é com o `DisplayAlerts`, ele por padrão é `true` e quando `false` não exibe as mensagens, respondendo de forma padrão as que precisam de resposta, porém como chamo esse método dentro do excel vba?

Já tentei usar `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, já tentei pegar o objeto que estou trabalhando e colocar `"obj".DisplayAlerts = False`, porém os `alerts` continuam rodando, como resolver isso?

Comment: Como está o código que chama o arquivo B, normalmente você precisa referenciar o que você está chamando, se não erros podem ocorrer. Que tipo de alertas que ocorrem? Veja este código `Application.EnableEvents = False` e `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: Ele está chamando colocando o arquivo dentro de um objeto que recebe tipo uma referência. Quando tento chamar esse objeto, por exemplo: `Dim objExcel` `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application"` `objExcel.Application.Visible = False objExcel.Application.Run "Planilha.xlsm"`

Comment: O [DisplayAlerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-displayalerts-property-excel) somente suprime avisos e mensagens da Aplicação Excel. Se o aviso for um erro do programa VBA, este não é suprimido pelo DisplayAlerts. E por favor insira o código com o exemplo do erro de executar códigos em WorkBooks diferentes.